# How can i capture the text inside this input box

Tags: jquery

I don't have a id to capture de text, i only have the id of the div

I tried

```
objeto=$('#TablaPaginadaNueva1_filter').parents('input'); 
userput=objeto.val();
```

but i can't have the value of the input box

```
<div id="TablaPaginadaNueva1_filter" class="dataTables_filter">

    <label>Buscar:<input type="search" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="" aria-controls="TablaPaginadaNueva1">
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('#TablaPaginadaNueva1_filter').find('input')` `parents` is the opposite of what you need https://api.jquery.com/find/

Comment: And how do you run that code? I see no event handler.

Comment: $("#TablaPaginadaNueva1_filter input").val();
try this

Comment: I use when the use change  a combo in the form

Comment: thank you smit raval this work !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var el = $('#TablaPaginadaNueva1_filter').find('input').first()

$(el).on('change', function(e){
  $('#output').html(e.target.value);
})

$('#setValBtn').on('click', function(){
  $(el).val('Hello');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="TablaPaginadaNueva1_filter" class="dataTables_filter">
  <label>Buscar:<input type="search" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="" aria-controls="TablaPaginadaNueva1">
    </label>
</div>


<h1 id="output"></h1>

<button id="setValBtn">Set value to Hello</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, and the last, if then I want to change the value of this box how can I do? I tried $(el)..val()=null; but doesn't work

Comment: I have added a button to show how to set the value.

Comment: Excelent Brad !

Answer (score 0):

you can get it with just one line of code:

```
var objeto = $('#TablaPaginadaNueva1_filter label input').val();
```

Then to clean the input box:

```
$('#TablaPaginadaNueva1_filter label input').val('');
```

Comment: Thank yoy Davide , and how can i clean the box ?  and want to clear after I retrieve the value

Comment: I have added to the solution also how to clear the input box after